# Export / import sub folder from Angular Library

Tags: angular

I am working with an Angular library that uses public-api.ts to export the elements of the application so other consuming applications can use them. For example:

public-api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/core.module';
export * from './lib/components/header/header.component';
export * from './lib/components/layout/layout.component';
export * from './lib/components/tenant-nav/tenant-nav.component';
export * from './lib/components/left-menu/left-menu.component';
export * from './lib/services/config-resolver.service';
export * from './lib/common/types';
export * from './lib/common/const';
```

I have a folder lib/common/const that contains files that export constants. This is one file for example:

```
export const LEFT_MENU_EVENT = 'Base.Menu.LeftMenuEvent';
export const APP_MENU_EVENT = 'Base.Menu.AppMenuEvent';
```

In my library I can import the variables from one specific file using

```
import * as CONSTANTS from './constants/myfile'
```

I wish to only import the constants file from my library in my consuming app. Here is the statement I wish to work:

```
import * as CONSTANTS from '@mylibrary/const'
```

How can this be done? It seems like everything that is exported in the public-api.ts file is flattened. I wish to reference a subfolder in my library similiar to

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
```

Comment: Why don't you just implement another [barrell](https://upgradetoangular.com/angular-news/angular-101-what-is-a-barrel-index-ts-file/) to handle this for you ? Make it export everything, and then just constants as well etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to export a file as a namespace instead of exporting a subfolder. This did the trick:

```
export * from './lib/core.module';
...
import * as ALL_KEYS from './lib/common/const';
export { ALL_KEYS };
```

Then I imported as:

```
import { ALL_KEYS } from '@mylibrary';
```

Comment: This approach still bundles  all scripts into one file, which is not friendly to webpack tree shaking.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 14:

1. copy the contents of the `public-api.ts` file to `src/lib/index.ts`
2. Delete the `public-api.ts` file because you won't need it anymore
3. Create a `index.ts` file in `src/lib/`
4. In the file json file `ng-packge.json`, change `lib.entryFile` to
   "./src/lib/index.ts"
5. In the `src/lib/index.ts` file, export everything that users can
   import from your library.